# Auto adjustable space between divs for 100% height

Tags: html, css

I've prepared a mobile site, which has the right aspect ratio of images, but on some phones with bigger screens it's to short and after the footer I get white gap. I would prefer to add some DIVs between contents which they would auto stretch when needed.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content1"></div>
  <div class="empty_gap"></div>
  <div id="accordion"></div>
  <div class="empty_gap"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

The `.empty_gap` DIVs would get evenly height so the page would fit the screen height. How to get this done? Or do you have any other solution for such a situation when the page is to short to fill the entire mobile screen?

**EDIT:** I have to add one thing which I didn't think before it will cause a problem. None of these solutions are working for me, because I use jquery accordion, and when I execute `$("#wrapper").outerHeight();` I get much bigger value than the screen size even when I have all panels collapsed. I guess that this is also the reason for flexible boxes that those solutions don't work too.

**EDIT2:** The JS solution is working now, I just needed to subtract the panel's content from the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with a JavaScript solution, try this:

Usually your `div`s should be wrapped with a `div` container. If it's not the case, then go ahead and add one like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content1"></div>
    <div class="empty_gap"></div>
    <div id="content2"></div>
    <div class="empty_gap"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Then in JavaScript, calculate the height of this container `div` and subtract it from the window's height. That would be the total of all your gaps, so divided by the number of your gaps (2 in your example) to get the height of each gap. Something like this:

```
var totalGap = $(window).height() - $("#wrapper").outerHeight();
var gap = totalGap / 2; //2 is the number of your gaps
$(".empty_gap").css("height", gap);
```

Place this code in event for when the page finished loading. However, if your app supports rotation, then you'll have to place this code in the `$(window).resize()` event.

Comment: You may also have to look for window resize events.

Comment: Also, FWIW, [you clearly don't need jQuery for this](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com).

Comment: @Roque You only need the `resize` event if your app supports rotation. AS for the your second comment, whether to use jQuery or not is a personal choice. The code above can be easily converted to pure JavaScript if the OP does not use jQuery already in his code.

Comment: Check my edit post. I've got this working finally. I need to do some more subtractions from the wrapper of the contents inside the panels. Thanks for the idea for solving this (I would prefer the CSS solution but I don't think if there is a way to get this done when having jq accordion as a content).

Comment: Agreed, I also prefer the CSS solutions and use them whenever possible, but I too had a project where they didn't work and had to come up with this JS solution, so I thought of sharing it. Remember to put the code in `$(window).resize` event if you want to support rotation. I disabled rotation in my project because I didn't need it and didn't like how the `resize` worked on different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use flexbox layout, for the equal space above and below `#content2` you will just need to set `#content2 { margin: auto 0; }` to make it to work.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20acL8xa/)**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
#content2 {
  margin: auto 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content1">content1</div>
<div id="content2">content2</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to support old browsers, it can be a job for [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Have a look [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for browsers support (94.22% support when used jointly the with `-webkit` prefixed version).

You just have to set your container element to `display: flex;` with `flex-direction: column;` then add `flex-grow: 1` (or anything > 0) to the `.empty_gap` elements.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header, #footer {
  height: 25px;
  background-color: red;
}

#content1, #content2 {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.empty_gap {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content1"></div>
  <div class="empty_gap"></div>
  <div id="content2"></div>
  <div class="empty_gap"></div>
  <div id="footer"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: This solution seems to be also good, I'd prefer more than JS but jquery accordion (I think) makes the problem that this doesn't work for me. See my post edit, if you can help in this new situation.

Comment: The flex layout will just make the content adjust to the container/wrapper size. You just need to make sure that this container fill the space you want it to fill. I am not sure how works jQuery accordion, but if the previous statement is verified, this should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it will be helpful in the future, because I didn't know anything about flexible boxes and how it can be done using them.